# Platformaticd db : adding custom object in entity data

Tags: fastify

1. In `platformatic` db, I have a entity. During get request I am trying to add additional key value to the object using entity hook and return the result. But in the response the custom key value is not receiving in API.
2. In categories I am storing the image id. The actual image information present the another table. How to get the image details during get all categories in api

Category current response:

```
[{ Id:1,name:a: imageId: 1, imageForSubCat:1},{ Id:2,name:aaa, imageId: 1, imageForSubCat:2}]


Images table schema 

Id, 
Url
Other dtl
```

In API, response I need in below format:

```
[{ Id:1,name:a: imageId: 1, imageForSubCat:1, catImageDtl: {image details}, subCatImageDtl:{imagedtl}},
{ Id:2,name:aaa, imageId: 1, imageForSubCat:2,catImageDtl: {image details}, subCatImageDtl:{imagedtl}}]
```

Category current response:

```
[{ Id:1,name:a: imageId: 1, imageForSubCat:1},{ Id:2,name:aaa, imageId: 1, imageForSubCat:2}]
```

Images table schema:

```
: 

Id, 

Url

Other dtl
```

In API response, I need in below format:

```
[{ Id:1,name:a: imageId: 1, imageForSubCat:1, catImageDtl: {image details}, subCatImageDtl:{imagedtl}},

{ Id:2,name:aaa, imageId: 1, imageForSubCat:2,catImageDtl: {image details}, subCatImageDtl:{imagedtl}}]
```